# on vacation vs go on vacation

Tags: grammar

Susan is on vacation now. 
Susan went on vacation last month.

What is the difference between "on vacation" and "go on vacation"? 
Does the former mean Susan is off work, she might be at home or might be in a tourist site? 
Does the latter mean Susan did not stay at home while she was on vacation?

Comment: The tense of the verb says nothing about whether she is at home or away. The use of _go (went)_ probably implies that she travelled somewhere for her vacation.

Answer (score 1):

“Going on vacation” refers to the change of state from “not on vacation to “on vacation”, similar to a light bulb “going out” when we flip its switch.

This usage may have originated from the idea that people do often go *away* on their vacations, but it is not limited to that meaning today.

Answer (score 1):

"On vacation" is an *adjective phrase* describing Susan's current state. "Go on vacation" is a *verb phrase*. They're different parts of speech, which makes it difficult to compare them in any meaningful way.

Perhaps some similar example pairs will make it clearer:

"*fall asleep*" and "*asleep*"
"*get on a train*" and "*on a train*"
"*sit in a chair*" and "*in a chair*"

Comment: "on vacation" is a prepositional phrase - it is headed by a preposition.

Comment: @JamesK It's both. It's a prepositional phrase, and the function in the example sentence is adjectival, similar to how "in the park" is a prepositional phrase and functions an adverbial because it answers the question "where"

Answer (score 0):

"On vacation" simply means "not at work" or "not in school", etc. - you're taking a break from your usual duties. If someone is on vacation now, it simply means they're taking time off. Some people travel for their vacations, but not everyone does - in fact, there's a colloquial term "staycation" for those who *stay* home rather than go somewhere else.

I agree with Kate Bunting that "going on vacation" may imply traveling, but in the end it really is a question for Susan ;)